# 2D Array fill with random numbers and output index c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to fill a 2d array with random numbers from 0 - 100;

Also, I'm trying to output the index of the row to output the random value inside the cells of the row.

The help I need is in displaying this output:

Sample Run

```
The sum of row0 elements {41 + 67 + 34 + 0 + 69} is 211
The sum of row1 elements {24 + 78 + 58 + 62 + 64} is 286
The sum of row2 elements {5 + 45 + 81 + 27 + 61} is 219
The sum of row3 elements {91 + 95 + 42 + 27 + 36} is 291
The sum of row4 elements {91 + 4 + 2 + 53 + 92} is 242
```

Check my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int const row = 5;
int const col = 5;

void input (int [][col]);
void output(int [][col]);

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    int array[row][col] = { 0 };

    input (array);
    output(array);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void input(int array [row][col])
{

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            array[i][j] = rand() % (100 - 1 + 1) + 1;
        }
    }
}

void output(int array[row][col])
{
    int sum;

for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    sum = 0;

    cout << "The sum of row" << i << " elements is {" << array[i][0];

    for (int j = 1; j < col; j++)
    {
        sum += array[i][j];
        cout << " + " << array[i][j];
    }
    cout << "} is " << sum << endl;
}

}
```

Comment: we just checked, and ... what is your question?

Comment: You haven't mentioned the issue you are facing.. so no one is able to help on this.

Comment: Your ouput function is missing on information to ouput...
And your counting the total value for each array, but losing the value for each one once it is done (except the last one).

Comment: `array[i][col]` accesses out of bounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the output() function with this

```
void output(int array[row][col])
{
    int sum;

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        sum = 0;

        cout << "The sum of row" << i << " elements {" << array[i][0];
        for (int j = 1; j < col; j++)
        {
            sum += array[i][j];
            cout << " + " << array[i][j];
        }
        cout << "} is " << sum << endl;
    }

}
```

This does the summing so get rid of the `int total` variable.  `int indexi` also isn't used.